# SparkAR How to change the lips size with code?

Tags: spark-ar-studio

Im creating a new filter effect but i wanted to change the size of the lips. I thought that the faceDistortionPack will solve the problem but it only widens it. I need to expand the upper lip and the lower. So i think it's necessary to script the code but i don't know about that. I tried to create one based on the tutorial in the site but it doesn't work. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use [Sculptgl](https://stephaneginier.com/sculptgl/) to make the face deformations.

1. Upload the "faceMesh.obj" (found in Face Reference Assets: [Face-reference-assets-classic.zip](https://origincache.facebook.com/developers/resources/?id=Face-reference-assets-classic.zip))
2. Make the changes you want in the face and save the new .obj
3. Spark Ar: Add a new Face Mash in your faceTracker OR use an existent one.
4. Select the Face Mash, go to "Deformations" -> Import New 3D Object
5. Voi a l